# Passing a function pointer within an array of parameters

Tags: c, function, pointers, void-pointers

I'm coding in C.

I have some nested function calls through all of which I pass and array of void* pointers in order to have a number of objects and doubles at hand.

The variable

```
void
    **param;
```

is passed through and within the functions I dereference it.

Now, I need to pass on a function pointer as well and by far the easiest would be to have this function pointer within the param array. But casting a function pointer to a void pointer is illegal. I was trying to pass on a pointer to my function pointer but I'm failing to dereference this void* into a function pointer.

How would you guys solve this problem?

----------------- SOLVED ------------------

As I'm not allowed to answer my own question before 8 hours, I edit my question:

I found it!

I defined a type for my function pointer

```
typedef double func_ptr(type1&, type2, type3);
```

and then used

```
// declare function pointer and assign value/function
func_ptr
    *func;
func = my_function;

// put pointer onto function pointer into array
void
    **param;
param[2] = &func; // [ space for this has been allocated somewhere ]
```

Dereferencing then works with

```
func_ptr
    *func = *((func_ptr **) param[2]);
```

Cheers

Comment: Ouch, sorry, totally forgot that. It's C.